# How to make sure all instances of all deployments receive azure cosmos change feed?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We are using change feed to invalidate local cache so we want all pods of all kubernetes deployments to receive the change feed. Should I set different lease prefix for each kubernetes pod so that it always receives every change feed?

Comment: Can you please add code snippets? What library are you using? How are you reading the change feed?

Comment: I can't share the exact code but it is implemented using java as shown in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/change-feed-processor?tabs=java#implement-the-change-feed-processor

Comment: @Venky - nobody should need to visit an external site to figure out your question. You have to provide a [mcve]. As written, there are no details at all. We know nothing about your k8s pods, your Cosmos DB setup, change feed setup... nothing at all. Please edit accordingly.

Comment: Yes you need to set a different lease prefix if you want each pod to read the changes independently. If they share a lease prefix (and leases collection) then they will be competing consumers and each pod will only see a subset of the changes as generally each batch will only be seen by one of the pods.

Answer (score 3):

Following the same document you linked has the answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/change-feed-processor?tabs=java#dynamic-scaling-1

> A single change feed processor deployment unit consists of one or more compute instances that have the same lease container configuration and the same leasePrefix, but different hostName values.

> ...within a deployment unit, you can have one or more compute instances. To take advantage of the compute distribution within the deployment unit, the only key requirements are that:

> - All instances should have the same lease container configuration.
> - All instances should have the same value set in options.setLeasePrefix (or none set at all).
> - Each instance needs to have a different hostName.

> ... then the change feed processor distributes all the leases in the lease container across all running instances of that deployment unit, and it parallelizes compute by using an equal-distribution algorithm. A lease is owned by one instance at any time, so the number of instances shouldn't be greater than the number of leases.

Thus, if what you want is to have **different Deployment Units**, each Deployment Unit **should have either**:

- A different lease container
- A different leasePrefix

Answer (score 0):

Setting lease prefix to the name of the pod as explained in [Programmatically get the name of the pod that a container belongs to in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253068/programmatically-get-the-name-of-the-pod-that-a-container-belongs-to-in-kubernet#:%7E:text=The%20pod%20name%20is%20written,getenv(%22HOSTNAME%22)%20.) fixed the issue. It is not necessary to set it to the name of pod; I could have set it to a guid which would have been unique for each and every pod but set it to the name of the pod so that it is easy to identify the items in the lease container.